# Vim multi-file version of '*' matching command

Tags: vim

In vim when you type `*` on a word (in command mode) it will do a quick search for all matches of that word, *in the current file* (and highlight the results if `hls` is set). Is there a quick way of doing this for all open files?

I know about `:grep` eg `:grep foo *.txt`. But that involves too much typing (especially on large variable names like `doStartCommenceTheWhizzyUpgradeThing`.

I know about https://github.com/vim-scripts/Greplace.vim for multi-file find and replaces.

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial solution, I thought I'd let others know. With your cursor on a word, type:

`:grep ctrl-r ctrl-w *.txt`. The `ctrl-r ctrl-w` will fill in the current word.

If you have your quickfix list setup, the results will be easy to navigate:

```
" quickfix list navigation                                                          
" ctrl-n, ctrl-m next, previous; ctrl-k kill (close list)                           
map <C-n> :cnext<CR>                                                                
map <C-m> :cprevious<CR>                                                            
map <C-k> :cclose<CR>
```

Comment: As a general rule you want to use `noremap` instead of `map` when possible. You also should specify a mode. e.g. `nnoremap <c-n> :cnext<cr>`.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I don't know the differences (map vs nnoremap, a mode) - I'll have to RTFM :-0